# Print function in JavaScript is not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript

Print function is not working and throwing error.

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'print')

```
function PrintPage() {
    var label = FindParent(document.getElementById("Label"), 'sectionHeader');
    var STable = document.getElementById('STable');

    var bodyHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = label.innerHTML + "<br/>" + STable.parentNode.innerHTML;
    document.parentWindow.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = bodyHtml;
}
```

Comment: So, `document.parentWindow` is undefined. How about using `document.defaultView`, as in `document.defaultView.print()`? According to http://help.dottoro.com/ljemhvhd.php  `document.parentWindow`  is specific to IE